# Obtain characters from one column based on input from column aside

Tags: r, while-loop, apply, do-while

I have a data frame `bp_example` that looks like the following:

```
 structure(list(Sequence = c("Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", 
"Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", 
"Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", 
"Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", 
"Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence", "Sequence"), start = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), end = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), 
    score = c(-0.205, -0.229, -0.115, -0.427, -0.327, -0.543, 
    -0.717, -0.923, -1.241, -1.471, -1.737, -1.717, -1.247, -1.137, 
    -0.689, -0.731, -0.337, 0.091, 0.579, 0.93, 0.575, 0.128, 
    -0.036, -0.186, -0.259), residue = c("M", "D", "A", "R", 
    "M", "R", "E", "L", "S", "F", "K", "V", "V", "L", "L", "G", 
    "E", "G", "R", "V", "G", "K", "T", "S", "L"), epitope = c(".", 
    ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
    ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "E", "E", "E", ".", ".", ".", "."
    )), .Names = c("Sequence", "start", "end", "score", "residue", 
"epitope"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

I am not really sure whether it is possible to do what I want, but anyway, here it is. I want to iterate over the column `bp_example$epitope` and, in case there are more than, say,  14 "Es" in a row i.e. 15 or more consecutive rows where an "E" appears in the column `bp_example$epitope`, I would like to have the corresponding characters on the previous column (`bp_example$residue`) printed as a single string (factor).

Considering the example that I gave,  I would like to have the string `MDARMRELSFKVVLLG`printed (best stored as an element of a `list` or `data.frame`).

I had a go with `while`loops, yet no success at all.

Comment: Or else what do you want?

Comment: Perhaps this helps `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(epitope=="E")][epitope=="E", list(residueConcat = if(.N>14) list(residue)), .(Sequence, grp)]`

Comment: do you know a way to get the output as a single character vector? I mean, I would like to get `MDARMRELSFKVVLLG` instead of `  [1] "   M" "   D" "   A" "   R" "   M" "   R" "   E" "   L" "   S" "   F" "   K" "   V" "   V" "   L" "   L" "   G"` (I did not formulate the question precisely I reckon)

Comment: I thought you said something about wanting a `list` output.  In that case, `setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(epitope=="E")][epitope == "E", .(residueConcat = if(.N > 14) paste(residue, collapse="")), .(Sequence, grp)]`

Comment: Your columns had some spaces `setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(epitope=="E")][epitope == "E", .(residueConcat = if(.N > 14) paste(trimws(residue), collapse="")), .(Sequence, grp)]$residueConcat
#[1] "MDARMRELSFKVVLLG"`

Comment: If you want a tibble back, something like `df %>% group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(epitope)) %>% summarise(string = paste(trimws(residue), collapse = ''), cnt = n()) %>% filter(cnt >= 15)`

Comment: @ sotos: perfect, it works absolutely fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), creating a run-lengh-id (`rleid`) column ('grp' based on the occurence of "E" value in 'epitome'.  Grouped by 'Sequence' and 'grp', we specify the logical condition in `i` (`epitome == "E"`) and `if` the number of rows (`.N`) is greater than 14, then `paste` the 'residue' elements together

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(epitope=="E")][epitope == "E",
     .(residueConcat = if(.N > 14) paste(trimws(residue), collapse="")), .(Sequence, grp)]
```

Comment: It worked with the format I have initially used. Would you please have a look at the new data.frame format I am using? I have just edited my question and if I run this code in the new data frame I get the following error: `Error in `:=`(grp, rleid(epitope == "E")) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: @BCArg I forgot a `,` before the 'grp := ' corrected it.  BTW, in the new example, the max number of row is 3 and you don't have any group that are greater than 14

Comment: @BCArg For the new example, `setDT(bp_example)[,grp := rleid(epitope=="E")][epitope == "E",.(residueConcat = if(.N > 2) paste(trimws(residue), collapse="")), .(Sequence, grp)]
   Sequence grp residueConcat#
1: Sequence   2           RVG`

Comment: it outputed a sequence with only three characters

Comment: @BCArg Yes, because I changed the `.N > 14` to `.N >2` as your example didn't have that many 14 E's.  You can change it to `.N > 14` in your original dataset

Comment: @BCArg It is because the conditions are set for `.N > 2` and in the example there are no cases where the number of rows are greater than 3 or 4 o4 other values

Comment: I understand. Although I ran that command on the very same data.frame, but with additional rows (where I had sequences longer than 3 characters) and the command only worked when `.N > 2`.

Comment: @BCArg If you can provide a more reproducible example, we can check it.  Have you checked if there are leading/lagging spaces in the 'epitope' column?

Comment: I've tried your code today and it worked (I might have forgotten to load the library last time). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An option using base R. I don't think you must use a loop to do this. In the code below, I suggest finding the matching indexes and in the resulting vector, find sequences with more than 14 elements:

```
#find matchin indexes
matching <- which(bp_example$epitope == 'E')

#separate vectors with elements in sequence
index <- split(matching, cumsum(seq_along(matching) %in% (which(diff(matching)>1)+1)))

#get the result by subscripting with indexes from vectors 
result <- lapply(index, function(x) if(length(x)> 14) paste0(bp_example$residue[x], collapse = ''))
```

To get the final result as a data frame, with each matching sequence as a new row:

```
as.data.frame(unlist(result))
```

Comment: great. Do you know how to store the output in a `data.frame` instead of in a `list`

Comment: How do you expect it in a `data.frame`? Each combination in a new row, or a new column? Because in your previous example, you had only one sequence that matched more than 14 'Es', but you could have many more.

Comment: exaclty, I would like to have each set of string > 14 in a new row

Comment: thanks. It returned a data frame, although there were some white spaces between the characters in the string. But nevermind, the code from akrun did already the job. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This happens because your original data has this spaces. To remove the spaces use: `gsub(" ", "", df, fixed = TRUE)`, considering `df` your resulting data frame.